# Query access with datetime criteria over two diffrent columns

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database file have these two columns and values

```
IODate(Date/Time)
IOTime (string)

IODate      IOTime
2013-02-04  11:20:52
2013-02-04  11:23:42
2013-02-04  11:52:02
2013-02-04  12:00:46
2013-02-04  12:53:34
2013-02-04  13:48:28
2013-02-04  13:52:12
2013-02-04  14:47:37
2013-02-04  14:47:51
2013-02-04  14:52:38
2013-02-04  14:53:38
2013-02-04  14:54:25
2013-02-04  15:08:28
2013-02-04  15:11:22
2013-02-04  15:11:33
2013-02-04  15:11:37
2013-02-04  15:12:46
2013-02-04  15:12:49
2013-02-04  15:12:51
```

Now I want to select values greater than datetime `(2013-02-04 11:20:52)` using Query
How can I do this. ??

Note : I can't make any schema changes in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a time to a date and query on that column:

```
SELECT t.IODate, t.IOTime, [iODate]+CDate([IOTime]) AS IODateTime
FROM IOData t
WHERE ([iODate]+CDate([IOTime]))>#2013-02-04 11:20:52#
```

Comment: Query buil was this `SELECT Atable.IODate, Atable.IOTime, [iODate] + CDate([IOTime]) AS IODateTime FROM [IOData] WHERE [iODate]+CDate([IOTime]) > #2013-02-04 13:48:28#` and I got this error `No value given for one or more required parameters.` ??

Comment: I have edited to suit your table name. The error suggests that you may need to edit further to match your names. The query was tested before posting.